# Goutte laravel web scrap from all table data

Tags: php, laravel

I need to scrap all Th and td data return like an array. Result showing only first Th/td data.

```php
$client = new Client();
$url ='https://schools.world-schools.com/school/munich-international-school/';

$page = $client->request('GET', $url);

$page->filter('table')->each(function ($item) {
    $this->results[$item->filter(' tr > th')->text()]= $item->filter('tr > td')->text();
});

dd( $this->results);
```

result showing only first Th/td, need to all row:

```
array:1 [▼
  "Year of Foundation" => "1966"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code is looping every table (`$page->filter('table')->each`) and selecting only a single `tr > th`. But what you want is to loop the `tr`'s of the table.

Probably you will need to do something like the following:

```php
$page->filter('#new_school_info tr')
    ->each(function ($item) {
        $header = $item->filter('th')->first();

        if ($header === null) {
            return;
        }

        $data = $item->filter('td')->first();

        $this->result[$header->text()] = $item->filter('td')->first()?->text;
        
        // Or for php versions below 8
        // $item->filter('td')->first()
        // 
        // $this->result[$header->text()] = $data ? $data->text() : null;
    });
```

Have not tested this myself.

Tip: Take a look at the [source](https://view-source:https://schools.world-schools.com/school/munich-international-school/) of the page and try to make the selectors.